# Android arrayadapter doesn't work well

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I'm a newbie.
I need to create a custom list that interact with two EditText(number) and a button. When the user click the button, it generates a list from the first number to the last number and check if the clicked number on list was prime or not... But i get an error in this part:
    ListView listMod;

```
            listMod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMod);

            List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
                listMod.add(i);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    lista);

            listMod.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

so i don't see what the problem is. I used this code also in another activity.
I'll post also the Whole activity:
package com.example.andre.thelist;

```
            import android.app.AlertDialog;
            import android.content.DialogInterface;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
            import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            public class TheList extends AppCompatActivity {


                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_list);
                    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


                    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Snackbar.make(view, "Maybe I can use this", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                        }
                    });



                    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gen);

                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            EditText firstn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstn);
                            EditText lastn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastn);
                            String firstnString = firstn.getText().toString();
                            String lastnString = lastn.getText().toString();

                            if(firstnString.isEmpty() == true || lastnString.isEmpty() == true ) {
                                Integer first = 1;
                                Integer last = 100;
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Verranno usate le cifre di esempio 1 e 100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            final Integer first = Integer.parseInt(firstnString);
                            final Integer last = Integer.parseInt(lastnString);

                            ListView listMod;

                            listMod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMod);

                            List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
                                lista.add(i);
                            }

                            ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                                this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                lista);

                            listMod.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                            listMod.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adattatore, final View componente, int pos, long id) {
                                    final Integer numero = (Integer) adattatore.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                                    //creo il ciclo di controllo valori
                                    if (numero > 0) {
                                        boolean isPrime = true;
                                        for (int i = 2; i <= numero / 2; i++) {
                                            if (numero % i == 0) {
                                                isPrime = false;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (isPrime) {
                                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(TheList.this).create();
                                            alertDialog.setTitle("Yeah numero primo");
                                            alertDialog.setMessage("Il numero " + numero + " è un numero primo!");
                                            alertDialog.show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Il numero " + numero + " non è un numero primo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            }

            });

            }
```

Thank you for any help

OK, I've modified the line (What a gaffe), but now the console show me other error like:

```
 Error:(70, 54) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,List<Integer>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<Integer>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<Integer>) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,Integer[]) is not applicable
 (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Integer[]) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
 constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

And

```
Error:(75, 22) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Integer>)
```

Also

```
 Error:(77, 22) error: cannot find symbol method setOnItemClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>)
```

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) { 
   listMod.add(i);
}
```

`listMod.add(i);` line causing issue because `listMod` is object of `ListView` and you are trying to call `add` method on it..

Use `lista` which is `ArrayList` for adding items in `ArrayList` which passing as data-source to Adapter:

```
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) { 
   lista.add(i);
}
```

As in update log:

> Error:(77, 22) error: cannot find symbol method
>   setOnItemClickListener()

problem is due to passing `this` as first parameter in ArrayAdapter.create adapter object as:

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                                TheList.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                lista);
```

Comment: And for the last two errors 75,22 77,22? You are my angel!

Comment: @andrepogg: both is related to each other see my updated answer

Comment: Error:(75, 22) error: cannot find symbol method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Integer>) it continues to show me that and the other one, but the 70, 54 doesn't shows up anymore